# How do I change text inside an element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm trying to change the text inside the below element but it's not working.

```
<div id='text'></div>
```

Below is the code I'm using. The `console.log` line works, however the text() function does not.

```
d3.json('/data', function(error, closure_data) {
  $('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('value') == '1') {
    console.log('1')
    text = d3.select('#text')
    $(text).text('1');
  }
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with d3, and I'm not sure why you're mixing d3 with jQuery there, but to do that part in plain jQuery is simply `var text = $('#text'); text.text('1');`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Didn't work

Comment: [Yes it does](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/g8Lo0n1e/).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oh, strange that it's not working for me in VS Code

Comment: you don't need to use jQuery if you have D3, you can just use `d3.select('#text').text('1')` without the need to have jQuery involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
 
$("#btnClick").click(function(){      
         $("div").text("your value in DIV");        
    });
```

```css
  div {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='submit' id="btnClick" value="ClickMe">
 <div id ="textDIv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer by Manjuboyz works, I went ahead and deleted my jquery script and just used d3, as recommended by my colleagues and by some people on this post. This is the resulting code.

```
d3.json('/data', function(error, closure_data) {
  var btn = d3.select('.dropdown-item')
  btn.on('click', function() {
    d3.select('#text').text('1')
  })
  });
```